# Extract the weights from several relationships in 1 cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to calculate a "corporation index" for a particular user based on how many times a user viewed or updated a file. In order to get this I'll assign values to certain paths. This is an example:

```
(u1:User {name: 'Alice'})-[:UPDATED]->(f:File)<-[:VIEWED]-(u2:User) // is worth 0.2 points
(u1:User {name: 'Alice'})-[:VIEWED]->(f:File)<-[:VIEWED]-(u2:User) // is worth 0.1 points
(u1:User {name: 'Alice'})-[:VIEWED]->(f:File)<-[:UDATED]-(u2:User) // is worth 0.2 points
(u1:User {name: 'Alice'})-[:UPDATED]->(f:File)<-[:UPDATED]-(u2:User) // is worth 0.5 points
```

The image shows a possible graph.
[image: a possible graph]

I want to know how a query has to look like that returns the following results.

```
User: Alice, User: Charly, index: (3 * 0.2) // 3 because there are 3 matching paths (Relationship with the lowest weight in the path)
User: Alice, User: Bob, index: (3 * 0.1)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
MATCH (u1:User {name:'Alice'})-[r1:VIEWED]->(f:File)<-[r2:UPDATED]-(u2:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u1:User {name:'Alice'})-[r3:VIEWED]->(f:File)<-[r4:VIEWED]-(u3:User)
RETURN u2.name, min(r1.weight) AS ViewUpd, u3.name, min(r3.weight) AS ViewView
```

This query doesn't work at all, but I hope it clarifies what I want.

Comment: Can you please give us more informations about your relationships (e.g if they have a weight property, which can be useful)

Comment: Of course. The relationships are labeled either VIEWED or UPDATED. The only property hey have is called weight, which indicates how often a user updated or viewed a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

Does this query do what you want?

```
MATCH (u1:User { name:'Alice' })-[r1]->(f:File)<-[r2]-(u2:User)
RETURN
  u2.name AS name,
  SUM(
    r1.weight * (CASE
      WHEN (TYPE(r1)= "VIEWED" AND TYPE(r2)= "VIEWED") THEN 0.1
      WHEN (TYPE(r1)= "UPDATED" AND TYPE(r2)= "UPDATED") THEN 0.5
      ELSE 0.2
      END)) AS index;
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=fgfvdg) showing this query, and here is a sample result:

```
+--------------------------------+
| name      | index              |
+--------------------------------+
| "Bob"     | 0.6000000000000001 |
| "Elvis"   | 1.5                |
| "David"   | 0.6000000000000001 |
| "Charley" | 2.1                |
+--------------------------------+
```

In my sample data, "Charley" has an `UPDATED` relationship and a `VIEWED` relationship with the `File` that is `UPDATED` by "Alice". The resulting `index` for Charley is the sum of the index values for both of those relationships.

Comment: Thank you! Almost there. Now I get the results like this:
Name: Sabine; data: { type: UpdUpd; index: 950 }
Name: Sabine; data: { type: UpdUpd; index: 550 }
Is it possible to get one line per user? I don't need data.type (if that helps), I just want to have a distinct user and the index value (in this case Name: Sabine; data: 1.500)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much